# How do I use ACE with my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, ace-editor

I want to use the [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/) online code editor in my project. How do I use it in ASP.NET MVC?

I'd like to save whatever edits are made with that editor in the database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume you have a strong typed model with a property called `Editor` with the data in it. Now use a normal `<div>` to load the data:

```
<div id="editor"><%=Model.Editor %></div>
```

Now you can create an ace editor in place of the div with javascript:

```
<script src="src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
};
</script>
```

Now when you want to save the data, for instance via a form post, use something like this to bind it back to the `Editor` property of the model:

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Editor, new { @id = "hidden_editor" }) %>

<!-- this is jQuery, but you can use any JS framework for this -->
<script>
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $("#hidden_editor").val(editor.getSession().getValue());
    });
</script>
```

In your controller you can now save the data to the database

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index (IndexModel model) {
    var data = model.Editor;
    // save data in database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using most recent technologies (Razor/MVC/Ajax) :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSave").on("click", function () {                
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id: @Model.ID,
                            html: ace.edit("editor").getValue() },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Changes saved.");
                    }                        
                });
        });
    });
```

In Controller :

```
    [AjaxAuthorize]
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult YourAction(string id, string html)
    {
        if (id == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        // do you stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it in Razor Views

```
@model OfficeGx.Cms.Model.ClassName
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CascadingStylesHdn, new { @id = "hidden_cssEditor" })
        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.CascadingStyles)
        <div id="cssEditor">@Model.CascadingStyles</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JavaScriptHdn, new { @id = "hidden_jsEditor" })
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.JavaScript)
        <div id="jsEditor">@Model.JavaScript</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var cssEditor;
    var jsEditor;
    window.onload = function() {
        cssEditor = ace.edit("cssEditor");
        cssEditor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/css");
        cssEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");

        jsEditor = ace.edit("jsEditor");
        jsEditor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
        jsEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
    };
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $("#hidden_cssEditor").val(window.cssEditor.getSession().getValue());
        $("#hidden_jsEditor").val(window.jsEditor.getSession().getValue());
    });
</script>
<style>
    #cssEditor, #jsEditor {
        position: relative;
        height: 400px
    }

    @Model.CascadingStyles
</style>
```

In my Controller Add/Edit Method

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult AddEdit(Article article, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            article.CompanyId = OperatingUser.CompanyId;
            article.CascadingStyles = article.CascadingStylesHdn;
            article.JavaScript = article.JavaScriptHdn;
```