# MVC: Ace editor post

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently writing a CMS system and I use the ACE syntax highlighter to highlight some HTML in a textbox.

Now, I have a form in which the contents are showed:

```
<div id="editor">@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body)</div>
```

The syntax highlighter is activated with the following javacsript:

```
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
    editor.renderer.setShowGutter(false);
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
</script>
```

But in my controller, I'm not getting the contents of the hihglighted textarea, which is normal because of the complex HTML that the syntax highlighter is generating.

Anyone who has an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before posting the data to the server, you have to assign it to a hidden field or back to the text area. This question was already answered [on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343855/how-do-i-use-ace-with-my-asp-net-mvc-application)

@Jan Jongboom uses the following code to assign the value of the ACE editor before the post:

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Editor, new { @id = "hidden_editor" }) %>

<!-- this is jQuery, but you can use any JS framework for this -->
<script>
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $("#hidden_editor").val(editor.getSession().getValue());
    });
</script>
```

This is MVC 2 markup, but can be easily adopted to Razor.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is a working solution, but I would like to avoid it because it means copy the data onto another element when it can be done in another way maybe. Anyway, I've marked the answer as accepted since I really appreciate your help. However, if you have another solution that doesn't require copiyng the data, I would like to know it from you.

Comment: I fear there is no other solution atm. If you look at the generated HTML, you can see that the TextArea doesn't hold the editor content. You have to extract the content from the editor and assign it to a field to get it on the server. What you can try is to assign it to the original TextArea before submitting (you would save the hidden field then, although keeping it shouldn't be much of a problem either).