# How do I use ACE for TextAreaFor in ASP.NET MVC5 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ace-editor

I am trying to Get `ACE` editor for `javaScript` purpose but i am not able to post my Editor data when i am clicking Save button its show `NULL` value in DB.
but when i am using normal `Textarea` without `ACE` my data is saving properly.

This is My CSHTML code.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-11" id="JavaScriptEditor">
        @Html.Label("JavaScript", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.JavaScript,new {@class="JavaScript"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JavaScript, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS Code:-

```
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("JavaScript");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/terminal");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    window.onload = function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $(".JavaScript").val().editor.getSession().getValue();
        })
    };
</script>
```

This is My Controller Code:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddEdit(Article article, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    article.CompanyId = OperatingUser.CompanyId;

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(article.Slug))
        article.Slug = article.Name.GenerateSlug();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(article.SlugKey))
        article.SlugKey = SlugKey();
    //bool isUnique = _articleService.IsSlugUnique(slug: article.Slug, articleId: article.Id);
    //if (!isUnique)
    //    article.Slug = $"{article.Slug}-1";
    article.CreatedById = OperatingUser.Id;
    article.ModifiedById = OperatingUser.Id;
    if (article.Tags != null && article.Tags.Any())
        article.Tag = string.Join(",", article.Tags);
    if (formCollection.GetValue("SubmitButton").AttemptedValue
        .Equals("Save and Publish", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        article.IsPublished = true;
    article.RoleIds = formCollection.GetValue("selectedRoles").AttemptedValue;

    if (article.Id > 0)
    {
        article.ModifiedById = OperatingUser.Id;
        _articleService.Update(article);
    }
    else
    {
        article = _articleService.Add(article);
    }
    return Json(new { RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Edit", "Content", new { area="cms", id = article.Id }) });
}
```

I am trying to Save This Property  data in Db but i am not able to  Save this Please Help me.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem with ace-editor?

Comment: Nevermind, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404850/mvc-ace-editor-post